# git fetch from remote, how do I then rebase?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch on my remote fork (which is behind my local master) and want to fetch the changes in that repo to my local machine. I do this using:

```
git fetch origin/branch-name
git checkout origin/branch-name
git switch -c "new-branch"
```

This does pull in the changes, but since this branch is behind master I cannot rebase onto master.

If I pull from the remote branch I get an `Already up to date`.

Is it possible to pull these changes from `origin/branch-name` in a way that allows me to rebase to master later?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `git fetch origin branch-name` above; `git fetch origin/branch-name` tells Git to treat the string `origin/branch-name` as a remote name. It's a bit confusing about when to use the slash and when not to (but that's Git for you...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does pull in the changes, but since this branch is behind master I cannot rebase onto master

You should still be able to rebase like that; it does not mater if the target commit is not in your ancestry.

What are you trying to do; rebase your newly-fetched `origin/branch-name` onto `origin/master`?

```
git checkout branch-name
git rebase master
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. If I do that my changes are seemingly overriden (at least they aren't at the top of the log). Also whats weird is if I rebase and then try to push this to the upstream directory for a pull request it errors with `fatal: couldn't find remote ref branch-name`

Comment: "couldn't find remote ref branch-name" -> If the branch does not exist on the remote then by default you have to push to `origin/branch-name`.

Comment: `at least they aren't at the top of the log` -> The commits may seem to have disappeared if the changes they include are already part of master. This is normal rebase behaviour unless you allow empty commits. Do the files look right; do the _files_ contain your changes?

Comment: this issue has been resolved. The reason that the commits disappeared after the rebase was that they were part of a previous PR that was merged, but then later reverted due to a performance regression. Reverted commits are apparently ignored by git if they are later attempted to be included again. I'm sorry for the confusion, but I didn't know that this was a possible explanation of the behavior, otherwise I would have mentioned it. Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it.